How to Build a .pkg.tar.zst package from an RPM Structured Source?
Before converting to Arch Linux, I'm preparing for my frequently used software, and I nearly finds all alternative form for my daily used software, except for my Canon Printer driver. Fortunately, the company provided the source for this, but it is well structured for RPM with a .spec file and many folders.
How to Build a .pkg.tar.zst package from an RPM Structured Source?
Here is the Source: cnijfilter2-source-6.20-1.tar.gz
Thanks.
